# Dockerfile autorun bash script report error

Tags: linux, bash, docker

I have a script which I want dockerfile autorun after image build container, I know it should be entrypoint command,but it doesnt work for me. Can someone help me to point out what is wrong for me

```
FROM centos:7.7.1908
ENV container docker

RUN yum install -y wget
RUN wget https://github.com/MGI-EU/ToolScieu.network_monitor.v1.0/network_monitor_scripts.zip

RUN yum install -y unzip 
#RUN ls

RUN unzip network_monitor_scripts.zip
#RUN unzip /root/network_monitor_scripts.zip
#RUN unzip -d /filess network_monitor_scripts.zip
RUN yum -y install net-tools
RUN yum -y install sed.x86_64
RUN chmod +x /filess/main2.bash
#RUN bash -c "filess/main2.bash"
#RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/filess/main2.bash"]
#RUN cp /filess/main2.bash /main2.bash
#CMD /filess/main2.bash
ENTRYPOINT [ "main2.bash" ]
#ENTRYPOINT /filess/main2.bash
```

Comment: after unzip the downloaded file, there is a folader named filess, and my script main2.bash is inside this folder

Comment: Did you try `ENTRYPOINT [ "/filess/main2.bash"]`?

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", what does happen?  The `ENTRYPOINT` as you have it now probably won't work (the script is not in one of the directories in `$PATH` but one of the commented-out forms or the suggestion from @ÖzgürMuratSağdıçoğlu seems like it should.  Also remember that the `ENTRYPOINT` is the only thing the container does, and then it exits.